# NuxtJS: How to pass params and query in URL

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I bought  a template from Luma-Nuxt JS and I tried to see their documentation but not a specific cover about routing for the newbie. So, now I want to pass query params through URL.
As you know, Standard routing can do that:

`<NuxtLink :to="{ path: 'details-classes/' + idData}"> {{ title }} </NuxtLink>`

But in Luma-NuxtJs using another concept is to pass route, I don’t fully understand, the code like that:

`<b-link :to="routeTo(routes.detailsClasses)" class="card-title d-inline-block text-truncate" style="max-width: 220px;" v-text="title" />`

So, how to insert `idData` in Luma-NuxtJs router?

Comment: perhaps `routeTo` is a vue methods, check it again and `b-link` is part of bootstrap-vue I guess

Comment: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/link

Comment: @kusiaga , I know it about boostrap-vue link, but I don't know how to pass data if using ```routeTo```. Do you have an example for pass data using ```routeTo```?

Comment: I dont know because the information about `routeTo` and `routes.detailsClasses` thing is not really clear. But in bootstrap vue, `:to` can accept string route like `/'details-classes/' + idData` or object

Comment: How to see the information about ```routeTo``` ?